# binding swipe to click event jquery

Tags: jquery, click, swipe

I'm trying to achieve the same effect that a click gives a person on a computer, but do it ALSO via swiping on an ipad/iphone. This is currently what my function looks like (this is for an image slider)

```
// Set the previous and next buttons
$('#suprflickrLB .lbImage .lbLeft').bind('click').click(function()  {
   $('#suprflickrLB').setLightboxData( 'prev', 'fade' );
   return false;
});
$('#suprflickrLB .lbImage .lbRight').bind('click').click(function() {
   $('#suprflickrLB').setLightboxData( 'next', 'fade' );
   return false;
});
```

I basically want people to be able to "swipe" their finger across the screen and have the same transition happen as "click" if that makes sense. I've tried a few jquery plugins to achieve the concept, but I'm not very fluent with jquery so I can' t seem to get this working.

If I added the jquery mobile library, could I do something like

```
$('#suprflickrLB .lbImage .lbLeft').bind('click').click(function() {
  $('#suprflickrLB').setLightboxData( 'prev', 'fade' );
  return false;
});

$('#suprflickrLB .lbImage .lbRight').bind('click').click(function()  {
   $('#suprflickrLB').setLightboxData( 'next', 'fade' );
   return false;
});

// Set previous and next buttons for swiping
$('#suprflickrLB .lbImage .lbRight').bind('swipe').swipe(function() {
   $('#suprflickrLB').setLightboxData( 'next', 'fade' );
   return false;
});
$('#suprflickrLB .lbImage .lbLeft').bind('swipe').swipe(function() {
  $('#suprflickrLB').setLightboxData( 'prev', 'fade' );
  return false;
});
```

Suggestions? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "swipe" is an correct event, use "swipeleft" or "swiperight".